# How to add/remove CSS class to parent element in jQuery dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, navigation, drop-down-menu, nav

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tatygrassini/tZBXe/

Horizontal dropdown menu with a 1 level deep submenu. All menu links with :hover styles.

Once parent clicked, submenu slides down, you hover out, submenu hides back, OK so far.

I want to give the parent `Add/Remove my CSS class` a CSS class (.focus), when clicked to change its background color to fake a "focus" state.

In the jsfiddle, when you click on the `Add/Remove my CSS class`, you'll see it changes its background-color to red for a second, this is because of the :active CSS style.
So, even when you hover on the submenu links, the parent link remains in "focus" state, but, when you hover out, the "focus" CSS class will be removed to achieve its normal state CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's an updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/tZBXe/2/
I've added

```
$(this).addClass("focus");
```

and in the hover function

```
$("a", this).removeClass("focus");
```